# Is there anything peculiar happening with General Relativity in $D=1+1$ dimensions?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity

I have noticed the following with Einstein's equations in empty space (with zero cosmological constant): when $T_{\mu\nu}=0$, the Einstein tensor is zero, $G_{\mu\nu}:=R_{\mu\nu}-\frac{1}{2}Rg_{\mu\nu}=0$, so when we contract this with the inverse metric $g^{\mu\nu}$ and using $g^{\mu\nu}g_{\mu\nu}=D$, we get
$$\left(1-\dfrac{D}{2}\right)R=0$$
This means that in empty space, for $D\neq1+1=2$, the Ricci scalar is zero, $R=0$. In this case, from $G_{\mu\nu}=0$, we also get that the Ricci tensor is zero, $R_{\mu\nu}=0$.

But, for $D=2$, we can't say that $R=0$, and thus cannot automatically say that $R_{\mu\nu}=0$ in empty space. Is this an indication that two-dimensional gravity is different in any interesting way than gravity for $D\neq 2$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To the contrary, vacuum general relativity in two dimensions is different from vacuum gravity in higher dimensions in a very **un**interesting way: There is no physical content to this theory unless you couple it to something else.

It has no propagating degrees of freedom (i.e. no gravitational waves) and all two-dimensional metrics are conformally flat. The Einstein-Hilbert action in two dimensions is a constant - the integral of 2d curvature is just the Euler characteristic of the surface by [Gauß-Bonnet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Bonnet_theorem) - and so there are no interesting equations of motion nor non-zero stress-energy tensors (since the stress-energy tensor is the variation of the action w.r.t. the metric!).

Comment: How does this sort of constraint translate into a more Hamiltonian formulation? I mean, I could plunk down a non-zero amount of matter around $x=0$ at $t = -\infty$ (or some time $-T$ for $T$ arbitrarily large) -- what goes wrong in asking the GR formalism to evolve the initial distribution of stress-energy and the metric forwards in time? Is it a question of the initial value being ill defined (because the metric and stress-energy have to be compatible for that time slice, and there's no way around it by having a parametrized stress-energy that starts small and grows nearly adiabatically)?

Comment: Many thanks for the answer. A follow up question: how does this coincide with the fact that in $D=2$ in empty space you cannot immediately say that the Ricci tensor vanishes? It (maybe naively) points to something less trivial than the empty space for $D\neq 2$.

Comment: @jwimberley That's the "unless you couple it to something else" - if you introduce matter you can get a non-trivial theory. The question, however, asks about *empty space* (i.e. vacuum solutions).

Comment: @TheQuantumMan That's already in the answer - in 2D Gauß-Bonnet tells us the integral over the Ricci scalar is the (non-zero, except for the torus) Euler characteristic, so the Ricci scalar/tensor can't be zero.